# App crashes on iOS 10.0.2 but not on iOS 10.1.1

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

My problem is my app (generated using Ionic) crashes on iOS 10.0.2 but not on iOS 10.1.1. Each time, I did exactly the same thing on the 2 devices.
I searched on Google and I didn't find anyone with a similar problem.

The crash comes from after a POST request to a server which have self-signed certificate. The only error in logs, on Xcode, is :

> Assertion failed: (isForProxy(authConfig.getConnectionType())),
>   function updateWithResponse, file
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-808.0.2/HTTP/HTTPAuthentication/AuthenticationHelpers.cpp,
>   line 1168.

Just before a crash, Xcode stopped as if I put a breakpoint. The concerned thread is named "com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader".

After a crash, I have to remove (or rebuild/run with Xcode) the app because, if not, it crashes directly when I launch from the device.

The concerned POST request (it seems to me very basic) is :

```
    $http.post(url, { data:  data } , { headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}})
          .success(function (data, status, headers, cfgApp) {
        // some code    
    }.error(function (data, status, headers, cfgApp) {
        // some code
    })
```

I have no idea how to correct this bug. I don't understand why it's work fine on iOS 10.1.1 and not on iOS 10.0.2 (tested with different devices for each version). Do someone reproduce a similar bug? Or is there something on iOS 10.1.1 which correct a bug like this?